# All possible Strings of length n for an input character - Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell, recursion, filter

I am attempting to generate all possible positions of an input character in a string made up of _'s and other letters where the input character can only replace the position an _ represents.

The code I have done so far is here:

```
possibleNewWords currentString letterInput listOfPossibleStrings currentColumn iterations
  | iterations == length currentString = removeDuplicates listOfPossibleStrings
  | (currentColumn == length currentString) && (currentString!!iterations == '_') = possibleNewWords iteredString letterInput listOfPossibleStrings 0 (iterations+1)
  | (currentColumn == length currentString) && (currentString!!iterations /= '_') = possibleNewWords currentString letterInput listOfPossibleStrings 0 (iterations+1)
  | currentString!!currentColumn == '_' = possibleNewWords currentString letterInput (possibleStringNormal:listOfPossibleStrings) (currentColumn+1) iterations
  | currentString!!currentColumn /= '_' = possibleNewWords currentString letterInput listOfPossibleStrings (currentColumn+1) iterations
  
  where
    possibleStringNormal = replaceInString currentColumn letterInput currentString
    iteredString = replaceInString iterations letterInput currentString
    
possibleNewWordsBlank currentString letterInput listOfPossibleStrings currentColumn iterations
  | iterations == length currentString = removeDuplicates listOfPossibleStrings
  | (currentColumn == length currentString) && (currentString!!iterations == '_') = possibleNewWordsBlank iteredString letterInput listOfPossibleStrings 0 (iterations+1)
  | (currentColumn == length currentString) && (currentString!!iterations /= '_') = possibleNewWordsBlank currentString letterInput listOfPossibleStrings 0 (iterations+1)
  | (currentString!!currentColumn == '_') && (currentColumn > (iterations+1)) = possibleNewWordsBlank currentString letterInput (possibleStringNormal:listOfPossibleStrings) (currentColumn+1) iterations
  | (currentString!!currentColumn /= '_') || (currentColumn <= (iterations+1)) = possibleNewWordsBlank currentString letterInput listOfPossibleStrings (currentColumn+1) iterations
  
  where
    possibleStringNormal = replaceInString currentColumn letterInput currentString
    halfIteredString = replaceInString iterations '_' currentString
    iteredString = replaceInString (iterations+1) letterInput currentString
```

The top function could generate a vast majority of the possibilities (it essentially put an input character in every available underscore, then permanently put a character in the first spot of the string the repeated the process until every _ had been replaced with the input character) but I realized it didn't account for cases such as `"_F_F_"`, so I tried writing the second function (possibleNewWordsBlank) and planned on combining the results and removing the duplicates of the final set but I could not get the remaining potential combinations to be output. That is when I realized I was probably approaching this entire problem incorrectly and thought it prudent to get some help.

An example of what I am trying to do is if we are trying to find all possibilities for `"____"` and the input character was 'F' then `["____", "F___", "_F__", "__F_", "___F", "FF__", "F_F_", "F__F", "FFF_", "FF_F", "FFFF", "_FFF", "_FF_", "_F_F", "__FF", "F_FF"]` would be output. I thought about trying to do something with reversing the strings from my first functions output but realized that would not cover all cases for larger n's.

An example of what I am trying to do with preexisting letters in the way is `"__F_W"` where the input character is 'G' would output `["G_F_W", "_GF_W", "__FGW", "GGF_W", "G_FGW", "GGFGW", "_GFGW", "__F_W"]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be coming at this from a fairly imperative style, as seen from your use of "iterations" and "currentColumn" and lots of list indexing.  A better idea would be to play into Haskell's strengths and think of this in a **functional** style.

To begin, try writing the type signature for the function you want.  I'll give this one to you:

```hs
replaceBlanks :: Char -> String -> [String]
```

Next, try to think recursively.  `Char` is not a recursive data structure, but `String` is, so a good place to begin is to pattern match on the `String`.  My stub would probably look like this:

```hs
replaceBlanks newChar [] = ...
replaceBlanks newChar (firstChar : restOfString) = ...
```

The next step to thinking recursively is the base case.  This particular example is actually trickier than it might first appear, but it's not too bad.  Ask yourself: What should my program produce if the caller provides the empty string as the second argument?

After that, you need to write the recursive case.  The trick here is to start by assuming your program works *and then write the program*.  I know, it sounds weird, but it actually makes sense when you think recursively.  What I mean is, pretend that if you call `replaceBlanks newChar restOfString`, then you magically get the correct answer.  Now, using that correct answer, can you extend it to turn into the correct answer for the call to `replaceBlanks newChar (firstChar : restOfString)`?  It will look something like this:

```hs
replaceBlanks newChar (firstChar : restOfString) = 
  let partialAnswer = replaceBlanks newChar restOfString
  in ...
```

Let's use your own concrete example.  You're trying to solve `replaceBlanks 'G' "__F_W"`.  That's a hard problem.  But, let's say that `replaceBlanks 'G' "_F_W"` magically works, and it correctly returns to you `["GFGW","GF_W","_FGW","_F_W"]`.  What can you do with this list to turn it into `["GGFGW","GGF_W","G_FGW","G_F_W","_GFGW","_GF_W","__FGW","__F_W"]`, the solution you ultimately want?  Do you see any patterns?  (Hint: the `map` function is your friend!)

Once you've filled in the `...` (and assuming you've done it right), then your program should magically work.  The magic of recursion!

Answer (score 1):

## A library-based solution:

The excellent answer by DDub nicely covers the case where you decide to use manual recursion. There is however an alternative possible style: don't use recursion yourself, just call Haskell library functions instead.

This alternative style is generally regarded as easier to read: for an experienced programmer, the name of the library function is good enough, and there is no need to check the workings of some ad hoc recursive scheme.

Besides, library functions are generally written by people who have a deep knowledge of the compiler optimization capabilities, which can lead to better runtime performance.

So in that style, you are to *avoid* direct use of recursion, and knowing your way around the Haskell language library is the important skill.

Of course, many library functions do use recursion internally, but that's the problem of somebody else.

### Experimenting ...

To test which functions are relevant to the problem at hand, the `ghci` runtime interpreter is a very useful tool. Let's start a `ghci` session, and define a couple of values:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 λ> 
 λ> wCh = '_'
 λ> newChar = 'G'
 λ> inputString = "__F_W"
 λ> goldenRes = ["G_F_W","_GF_W","__FGW","GGF_W","G_FGW","GGFGW","_GFGW","__F_W"]
 λ>
```

So we have a *wildcard* character, hardwired to '_' in your code, a replacement character, 'G', an input string, and a result to check against, up to some reordering.

How many wildcards have we got in "__F_W" ?

```
 λ> 
 λ> length $ filter (==wCh) inputString
 3
 λ> 
 λ> wCount = length $ filter (==wCh) inputString
 λ> 
 λ> wCount
 3
 λ>
```

For each wildcard, we have a choice of either '_' or 'G' in the output, and we must form the *Cartesian product* of all these possibilities, kindly provided by the [sequence](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=sequence&scope=set%3Astackage) library function:

```
 λ> 
 λ> replicate wCount [wCh, newChar]
 ["_G","_G","_G"]
 λ> 
 λ> sequence $ replicate wCount [wCh, newChar]
 ["___","__G","_G_","_GG","G__","G_G","GG_","GGG"]
 λ> 
 λ> repss = sequence $ replicate wCount [wCh, newChar]
 λ> repss
 ["___","__G","_G_","_GG","G__","G_G","GG_","GGG"]
 λ> 
 λ> length repss
 8
 λ>
```

Now, we have to *spread* the contents of each string from `repss` such as “GG_” into our main input string. This task is an example of a *stateful list traversal*, where the output item depends on both the input item and some *state* that we have to maintain and carry along. In our situation, the state is the remaining part of “GG_”.

Such a task is often carried out thru the [`mapAccumL`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:mapAccumL) library function. As far as we are concerned here, the type of the `mapAccumL` function is `(s -> a -> (s, b)) -> s -> [a] -> (s, [b])`. The *state* is also known as the *accumulator*, hence the choice of name.

The first argument of `mapAccumL` is a **step function**, which takes an input character together with an incoming state, and returns an output character and a new state. The second argument is the initial state, that's “GG_” in our situation. The `mapAccumL` function returns the final state paired with the output list.

Our step function is to change a wildcard character, and leave the other ones unchanged:

```
 λ> 
 λ> stepFn  =  (\st ch -> if (ch == wCh)  then  (tail st, head st) else  (st, ch))
 λ> 
 λ> import Data.List (mapAccumL)
 λ> 
 λ> mapAccumL stepFn "GG_" inputString
("","GGF_W")
 λ>
```

At that point, we can define our `spread` function:

```
 λ> 
 λ> spread inputStr reps = snd $ mapAccumL stepFn reps inputStr
 λ> 
 λ> spread  "__F_W"  "GG_"
"GGF_W"
 λ>
```

And we just have to map this operation on all the members of `repss`:

```
 λ> 
 λ> map  (spread inputString)  repss
["__F_W","__FGW","_GF_W","_GFGW","G_F_W","G_FGW","GGF_W","GGFGW"]
 λ>
```

**Sanity check:**

```
 λ> 
 λ> result = map (spread inputString)  repss 
 λ> result
 ["__F_W","__FGW","_GF_W","_GFGW","G_F_W","G_FGW","GGF_W","GGFGW"]
 λ> 
 λ> import Data.List (sort)
 λ> 
 λ> sort result
 ["GGFGW","GGF_W","G_FGW","G_F_W","_GFGW","_GF_W","__FGW","__F_W"]
 λ> sort goldenRes
 ["GGFGW","GGF_W","G_FGW","G_F_W","_GFGW","_GF_W","__FGW","__F_W"]
 λ> 
 λ> sort result == sort goldenRes
 True
 λ>
```

So we have the result we wanted, except for some reordering.

**Putting it all together:**

```
newStrings :: Char -> Char -> String -> [String]
newStrings wCh newChar inputString =
    let
         wCount  =  length $ filter (==wCh) inputString
         repss   =  sequence $ replicate wCount [wCh, newChar]
         stepFn  =  (\st ch -> if (ch == wCh)  then  (tail st, head st)
                                               else  (st, ch))
         spread  = \str reps  ->  snd (mapAccumL stepFn reps str)
    in
         map  (spread inputString)  repss
```

**Final test:**

```
 λ> 
 λ> :load q66665241.hs
 Ok, one module loaded.
 λ> 
 λ> newStrings  '_'  'G'  "__F_W"
 ["__F_W","__FGW","_GF_W","_GFGW","G_F_W","G_FGW","GGF_W","GGFGW"]
 λ>
```

So we have a solution that does not use recursion directly, and that fits into 10 source lines of reasonably short width.